# Convert input list with for loop into uppercase

Tags: python, list, for-loop, uppercase

im trying to print this input list in uppercase but i always become an attribute error. I tried many ways but i still can't solve it. could someone help me? Thank you and sorry for my english :))

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in x:
    x[i] = input("Enter your name")
print(x)
```

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? You simply want a program that asks you for your name ten times and stores the input in a list?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are creating an array with defined values (all integers), but immediately replace it with an input string.

Just do:

```
x = list()

for i in range(0, 10):
   input_name = input("Enter your name") 
   x.append(input_name.upper())
```

Comment: This will raise an error since `x` has no element and you're trying to assign values to `ith` element. You need to replace `x[i] = input_name.upper()` with `x.append(input_name.upper())`

Comment: Sorry yep x.append, did this in a rush